# Calculating time and velocity using vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

For my homework, I was given a set of river problems relating to vectors.
What I am really struggling with is creating a diagram out of the given information as I always fail to make an accurate representation of the provided information.

As for an example, here is a question which I do not quite understand.

[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRzXZ.png)

> Mary leaves a dock, paddling her canoe at 3 m/s. She heads downstream at an angle of $30^\circ$ to the current, which is flowing with 4 m/s.
>
> 1. How far downstream does Mary travel in 10s?
> 2. What is the length of time required to cross the river if its width is 150m?

So, what I have tried to do is:

Since I know that the triangle is a right-angled (Would be greatly appreciated to know of a way to determine whether each triangle is right-angled or not since I only based this assumption on my diagram which again, in my opinion, isn't accurate.) I have tried plotting a diagram to visualize the question ([You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olEoK.jpg)), and solving for side d using sin. However, I got that d = 3sin30, which when I tried finding the time using the formula d = vt, I got the wrong answer according to my textbook.

I really am lost, and I don't completely understand where I messed up. Could someone perhaps explain to me what I have done wrong? I am almost sure that I didn't draw the diagram correctly as I feel that the problem is with my understanding of the question.

Thanks a whole bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several assumptions/ misconceptions, you almost found. First one, there is no need for right angle. In fact, in your figure, for a right angle triangle the hypotenuse ($3$) must be greater than any of the sides (you have one with length $4$). So let's start from your figure, but you need to keep only the line denoting the motion of the canoe, at $30^\circ$ with respect to the current. If there would be no current, in one second the canoe will travel $3\sin 30^\circ$ meters in the direction across, and $3\cos 30^\circ$ down the river. If you add the current, it has no component in the perpendicular direction, so you still move $3\sin 30^\circ$, but in the downstream direction the canoe is traveling $3\cos 30^\circ+4$ meters. To draw the diagram, start with the speed of the canoe vector, as you have done in your figure, then from the end of that vector draw a vector of length $4$ in the downstream direction. To obtain the velocity with respect to the starting point just join the starting point with the end of the vector representing the current velocity.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have a small question: since you're using SOH-CAH-TOA, is this triangle is right-angled?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "SOH-CAH-TOA" means.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. It is basically a way of saying that you're computing the sine, cosine, and tangent of an angle/side in right-angled triangles. So, what I'm trying to ask is that since you're calculating the sine and cosine of the side, is this triangle right-angled? Or did you use the law of cosines?

Comment: You can decompose the velocity of the canoe onto perpendicular axes (that's why you have right angle triangle). In this case I choose the direction down the stream for one axis, and the direction perpendicular to the stream for the other axis. You don't need to do this, but it's a nice trick that helps simplify calculations. I could find all quantities using generalized Pythagoras' theorem, but it's more work.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for taking the time and answering my question, I truly appreciate it!